# I want to assign fields with mongoengine?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine

I have the following query:

```
Family.objects('name': 'bob')
```

which returns:

```
{'_id': 22, 'name': 'bob', 'age': 12, 'height': 176}
```

But I just need `age`

I can do it with `mongodb`:

```
db.family.find({'name': 'bob'}, {'age': 1})
```

But, how can I do it with `mongoengine`?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is the [`only()`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.queryset.QuerySet.only) method.

```
Family.objects(name='bob').only('age')
```

If you use `get` then use `.` to access fields' values

```
Family.objects.get(name='bob').age
```